# unable to view any output

Tags: jquery, html

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myFirstStyleSheet.css">

            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>

            <script>
                $.getJSON('/Users/skhare/tableList.json', function(tableList) {
                var output="<table id=tableStyle>";
                output+="<tr>" + "<th>" + "Table Names" + "</th>" + "</tr>";
                for (var i in tableList.t)
                {
                    output+="<tr>" + "<td>" + "<a href=/Users/skhare/tableDescription.html>" + tableList.t[i].name + "</a>" + "</td>" + "</tr>";
                }

                output+="</table>";
                document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
              });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
          <div id="placeholder"></div>
        </body>
      </html>
```

The above code does not display anything and also does not display any error.
the **json file** is as :

```
{"t":
  [
      {"name":"DIM_BROWSER"},
      {"name":"DIM_CAMPAIGN"},
      {"name":"DIM_COLOR_DEPTH"},
      {"name":"DIM_CONNECTION_TYPE"},
      {"name":"DIM_COUNTRY"},
      {"name":"DIM_GEOGRAPHY"},
      {"name":"DIM_JAVASCRIPT_VERSION"},
      {"name":"DIM_LANGUAGE"},
      {"name":"DIM_OPERATING_SYSTEM"},
      {"name":"DIM_PAGENAME"}
    ]
  }
```

Comment: Check the console. Chances are the JSON file is not getting loaded.

Comment: You will need to run the script after pageload ...  ie use `window.onload` or `$(document).ready(...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the script code inside [$(document).ready()](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON('/Users/skhare/tableList.json', function (tableList) {
        var output = "<table id=tableStyle>";
        output += "<tr>" + "<th>" + "Table Names" + "</th>" + "</tr>";
        for (var i in tableList.t) {
            output += "<tr>" + "<td>" + "<a href=/Users/skhare/tableDescription.html>" + tableList.t[i].name + "</a>" + "</td>" + "</tr>";
        }

        output += "</table>";
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML = output;
    });
})
```

Comment: @sonal you need to check this question as a correct one. It is the way you thank an author :)

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, the reason that this is not working for you is that you are trying to manipulate elements (i.e. `<div id="placeholder">`) before the DOM has finished rendering and they are present on the page.

However, my advice would be to move all of your JavaScript to before the closing `</body>` tag, as opposed to using `$(document).ready()`. This helps to keep your code organised (as all of the JS will be in one place) and has the added advantage that, by this point, the DOM will have rendered by definition.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="myFirstStyleSheet.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="placeholder"></div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $.getJSON('/Users/skhare/tableList.json', function(tableList) {
        var output="<table id=tableStyle>";
        output+="<tr>" + "<th>" + "Table Names" + "</th>" + "</tr>";
        for (var i in tableList.t)
        {
          output+="<tr>" + "<td>" + "<a href=/Users/skhare/tableDescription.html>" + tableList.t[i].name + "</a>" + "</td>" + "</tr>";
        }

        output+="</table>";
        document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=output;
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```